# Microsoft Windows Search Indexer running high on CPU, RAM and Disk - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, services, search-indexing

This problem started recently on a Windows 10 laptop I was using (with an Intel i7 7th gen and ADATA 8GB RAM). At first I assumed Outlook had a problem since I initially saw that it was running the HDD to 90-100% usage on the Task Manager. RAM and CPU were fine at this point, but Outlook couldn't update it's mailboxes, and kept crashing soon after, even when running in Safe Mode. After ending all Outlook tasks to get a better idea from the Task Manager as to whats going on, I see mainly Windows services such as System and Service Hosts running the disk high on usage. The main one being Microsoft Windows Search Indexer. I troubleshooted as followed:

Ran the Seach and  Indexing troubleshooter wizard. This came up frst saying the "Windows Search  is not working" in the diagnostics check. Running the "Try these Repairs as Administrator" option then "Fixed" the problem but this proved to be unreliable.

Tried to end the Search process running in the Task Manager with no luck, before accessing Services and stopping Windows Search before disabling it and applying the changes. This also didn't work after rebooting the system.

Installing Windows updates did not work either (that includes Feature Update  of Windows 10, version 20H2) , nor did trying to uninstall  updates since the last Windows updates done prior to that were not recent.

Rebuilding the Index via Indexing Options and rebooting the system didn't work either.

At this point I assumed it was a problem with the HDD, and ran a few tests with HDTune and Crystal Disk , but they showed the disk was healthy. Regardless, I cloned the drive to a new SSD. The problem still persisted  with the Search Indexer, and this time it ran high on RAM and CPU usage.

So its probably not a hard drive issue, but after disabling Windows Search and rebooting the new SSD, the system performed at normal usage levels with Outlook able to Send and Receive efficiently and mailboxes syncing as they should. Other services and applications were runnning normally too with only momentary highs on the system. Windows Search Indexer does notify me that its disabled and if I would like to re-enable it. I am holding off on that for now but I know that this doesn't really solve the problem. Has anyone else come across this issue before and has any guidance on what I could do next? I'm worried that this is not the last time I have this problem with the system. Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I would do as follows: From an admin prompt run: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile`.  Let that run for 1 min, hopefully to capture the issue then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`.  If you get Windows Performance Analyzer from the Store or by downloading the Windows 10 SDK and installing the Performance Toolkit, you should be able to open the ETL trace, focus on the process in question and look where it sends most of it's CPU time and the associated stacks.  With Symbols configured it should make some sense.

Comment: @HelpingHand Sorry its taken me this long to get back. I was not able to run the commands you mentioned as we had to just quickly implement a round about solution. On the new SSD I mentioned above, under Indexing Options I disabled indexing for Outlook. This introduced another problem where the passwords to the mailboxes weren't being remembered by Outlook. For that, in Powershell as Admin I ran this command: 
Get-ScheduledTask | foreach { If (([xml](Export-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName -TaskPath $_.TaskPath)).GetElementsByTagName("LogonType").'#text' -eq "S4U") { $_.TaskName } }

Comment: @HelpingHand Made a note of the tasks listed, went to Task Scheduler and disabled the program that was listed. Rebooted and the laptop was working fine with minimal overhead from Outlook and no overhead from the Search Indexer. I'm not mentioning it as a proper solution though, because as it stands Windows Search Indexer is still disabled which has a few small issues when searching emails and sorting them. I'll try your suggestion when I get the older driive up and running. For now this seems to be workking out much better than what I was experiencing before.